# Create backup of MS SQL 2005 DB without full-text indexes and catalogs

Tags: sql, backup

Good day!

My new hosting provider doen't support restoring MS SQL backups with full-text indexes\catalogs inside.

I can't found any way to create a backup without full-text capabilities inside. One way is to drop fulltext catalog and indexes, do a backup and then revert changes back, but if there any better way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look like it's that easy or even possible.

https://serverfault.com/questions/1/how-to-exclude-indexes-from-backups-in-sql-server-2008

Never tried it myself but seems an odd request from your hosting provider.

Comment: I finally drop my index before on a local copy, restore it on the server and recreate it by hand on the server...